# How to configure eclipse build path to develop an ant task ? Is there a plugin for ant tasks dev?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

I need to develop an ant wrapper to an automated task implemented in java, and I'm going to do this with eclipse, and I want to do it by extending ant's Task class.

Since eclipse already has an integrated version of ant, I would feel like a kind of waste to add my own copy of ant.jar somewhere. I'm looking for a way to indicate that i need "this major version of ant" for my project, and let eclipse do the rest of the work. A bit like when we configure a project to use "A J2SE 1.6 runtime", and not "The exact specific version of the jre installed here".

I checked Project context menu -> Build path -> Add library, and I was expecting to find something like "Ant" in the library type selection popup, next to JRE System Library, EAR Library, Google app engine, etc... And I did not find it.

Also, there is not "Ant task" project template.

Am I missing a plugin here ? Is there a smart thing to do ? Or do I just have to drop ant.jar in a lib/ directory in my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "User Library" containing the Ant jars from your Eclipse install and add this to your project's build path.

- Project / Build Path / Configure Build Path
- Add Library / User Library
- Click the User Library button
- Give it a name, e.g. "ant" or "eclipse-ant"
- Click Add JARs...
- Navigate to the ant plugin dir in your Eclipse installation

  - e.g. eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145\lib
- Select some or all of the jars
- Finish

Those jars are now on your build path.

Comment: I first tried this, it works, but I was wondering I not sure referencing a jar directly from a plugin directory is a good thing. I was looking for an abstraction of that, something that says "I use ant 1.7", like when configure the project to use a "Java SE 1.6 runtime" and not the precise location and minor version of the JRE

Comment: I understand your point. But in your question you said - "I would like to compile my project againts this integrated version, rather that having my own copy of ant.jar somewhere."

Comment: You're right, that was not very clear. I'm going to fix this part. Still +1 for the research effort.